# How can I protect ASP.NET sites behind a Windows password and forms authentication?

Tags: iis, authentication, iis-7

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC site that utilizes forms authentication for part of the application. During development, I need to be able to give external parties access to a development server hosting the site. Since I don't want to expose the site to the entire internet, I need to password protect it while still allowing forms authentication to be in use.

Mixing of Windows and forms authentication doesn't work. Is there a standard way of doing this? I would have to think this is a common scenario. The article on MSDN doesn't seem to apply to my situation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx

**Update:** The first two answers suggest adding in standard IIS basic/digest authentication. As far as I know, this is not compatible with forms authentication because the user's identity will be set to the Windows account, not the identity used through forms authentication. I need the two to be completely independent. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You could protect it in IIS, give those details to the external parties, and leave the forms auth as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Disable anonomous access to force the users to login via a windows account before accessing the site.

Comment: The problem with this is that the they can't access the forms-protected portion of the site as their user will already be set to the Windows account, which is unrelated to their site accounts.

Comment: Not really--disabling anonomous access forces one to do a windows login to access the pages. The forms stuff can then work behind it. Key here is the disabling anonomous access while not adding another form of authentication.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. Leaving only Forms Authentication enabled in IIS 7, when going to the site I get redirected to the Forms Authentication login url which in turn shows a standard IIS 401 unauthorized error. What I want is a Windows prompt before anything else.

Comment: Ah, never mentioned IIS7 and I missed the tag. For that angle, perhaps you could tweak the config to require authenticated users for everything, even the "public" parts of the site. No real good way to do this in IIS7 otherwise.

Comment: One other thought--I think you can disallow the anonomous user from reading the folder and force a http authentication prompt, even on IIS7. Haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately what you're trying to do is not possible in IIS7 (integrated mode), but there is a workaround. I suggest you to [read this article](http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/) written by Mike Volodarsky a former program manager for IIS7 at Microsoft. Article addresses your problem and there is even a sample code you could use.

Answer (score 0):

I knew a guy who did this using Apache and a reverse proxy.

http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Comment: I actually like the reverse proxy idea, but I don't want to add Apache into the mix. I'm going to see if ARR for IIS might be able to do this.